# Ignore undefined key in argument (it's defined in the macro before it's used)

Tags: macros, xstring, key-value

How can I make this macro initially ignore the undefined key `fn-special-text` in the second argument? It is defined within the macro (because the name is generated from the text of the first argument; that all happens in the first two steps), then *set* using that argument only *after* that definition is generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{keyval}
\begin{document}

% The command:
\newcommand\annMessageParseParse[2]{%
  % first step, search for the instance of `FN...` in arg #1
    \StrCut{#1}{FN}\partA\partB% take unique name starting after "FN"
    \StrCut{\partB}{ }\partC\partD% stop at the first space
  % generate a new key using that unique name:
    \makeatletter
    \define@key{mykeys}{fn-\partC-text}{\expandafter\def\csname fn\partC text\endcsname{#1}}
    \makeatother
  % set the key using arg #2
    \setkeys{mykeys}{#2}
  % create a command using the new name, which employs our new key (which is just a footnote command)
    \expandafter\def\csname FN\partC\endcsname{\expandarg\footnote{\expandafter\csname fn\partC text\endcsname}}
  % combine `FN` and `\partC` in order to use the so-named command we just made
    \edef\combinethem{FN\partC}
  % replace the old `FN...` with the new command
    \expandarg\def\thenewmessage{
      \StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{\combinethem}
      {\csname FN\partC\endcsname}
    }
  % spit out the message
    \thenewmessage
}

% use case:
  \annMessageParseParse
    {This is myFNspecial new message.}% will turn into `This is my^[1] new message`
    {fn-special-text={This is the special footnote}}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that, when the macro is called, keyval sees the undefined key immediately and errors out. Is there some way I can tell keyval (or xkeyval?) to just ignore undefined keys? Both the message and the *yet to be defined* key need to be made in arguments in the same command.

Comment: There is no problem here if you move the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` setting *outside* your definition of the macro `\annMessageParseParse`.

Comment: But that doesn't answer your question regarding unknown keys, right?

Comment: Right, but that's actually really good to know! Eventually I want to be able to make this process start by counting how many `FN...`'s are in the message, then do this stuff to each one - so it'll be much cleaner now to just wrap the whole macro def in `\makeatletter`/ `\makeatother` once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could redefine `\KV@errx` which will be expanded in case of undefined keys. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\begin{document}

%\setkeys{test}{unknown=something}

\makeatletter
\let\KV@errx@ORI\KV@errx   % Save original error handling

\let\KV@errx\@gobble       % Ignore unknown keys
\setkeys{test}{unknown=something}

\renewcommand\KV@errx[1]{% Ignore unknown keys, but print a warning
  \PackageWarning{test}{#1}}
\setkeys{test}{unknown=something}

\let\KV@errx\KV@errx@ORI   % Restore original error handling
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel - this is exactly what I needed! I am writing the macro into an .sty document. Any reason why it only works if I redefine  `KV@errx` at the end of the package? (That's no problem; it just might be useful to know why it works that way in the future).

Comment: Redefining `\KV@errx` should work at any time after loading the `keyval` package. But it's a good idea to redefine it right before the usage of `\setkeys` and restore it immediately afterwards. Without restoring it this would affect all other packages using `keyval` as well which would be a very very bad idea.